Feedback on and assistance with this proof about a particular quotient space of $\mathbb{C}P^1$
The goal here is to define the particular equivalence relation I'm attempting to describe, and then provide an equation (in this case, (2)) that can be used to determine whether or not two given parametrizable curves in $\mathbb{C}P^1$ are of the same equivalence class under the equivalence relation.
I'm particularly concerned with whether or not everything I've chosen to define along the way is in fact well-defined or if I need to retype a few things in slightly different ways in order for any of it to make sense, including syntactically.
Also, most of all, I'm relatively new to to the notation conventions in abstract algebra as well as many of the notation conventions in mathematics more generally, so I want to know if I'm doing anything in an unnecessarily non-standard way that could be cleaned up to improve the proof.

Preliminary definitions:
Define:

$C:\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^1$
$$(x,y,z) \mapsto \sqrt{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+i\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$$
$R: \mathbb{R^3}\times\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$
$$R\left((x,y,z),(\theta,\phi)\right)=\left((\cos{\phi}+\frac{z\sin\phi}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})(x\cos{\theta}-y\sin{\theta})\right)\hat{i}$$ $$+\left((\cos{\phi}+\frac{z\sin\phi}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})(x\sin{\theta}+y\cos{\theta})\right)\hat{j}$$ $$+\left(z\cos{\phi}-\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\sin\phi\right)\hat{k}$$
$S:\mathbb{C}P^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$
$$z \mapsto \left(\lim_{w \rightarrow z}\frac{2\Re(w)}{|w|^2+1}, \lim_{w \rightarrow z}\frac{2\Im(w)}{|w|^2+1}, \lim_{w \rightarrow z}\frac{|w|^2-1}{|w|^2+1} \right)$$
$\forall X,Y\subseteq \mathbb{C}P^1$,
$$X \sim Y \iff \exists (u,v)\in\mathbb{R^2} :Y=C\circ R\left(S(X),(u,v))\right)$$ $\tag1$

Note that in $\mathbb{C}P^1/\sim$ we have:

$\forall z \in \mathbb{C}P^1$, the equivalence class of $z$ is $\mathbb{C}P^1 $
$\overline{\mathbb{C}P^1}=$ {$\mathbb{C}P^1$}
$\overline{\mathbb{C}}=${$U:U=\mathbb{C}P^1\setminus${$z$} for some $z\in\mathbb{C}P^1$}
$\forall X\subseteq \mathbb{C}P^1$, $\overline{X}$ $=$ {$Y\subseteq\mathbb{C}P^1:Y=C\circ R\left(S(X),(u,v)\right)$ for some $(u,v)\in\mathbb{R^2}$}


What I wish to prove:
Suppose:

$r\subset\mathbb{R}$ is connected

$\gamma_i(t):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}P^1$ for $i=1,2$

$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

$X=$ {$z\in\mathbb{C}P^1:z=\gamma_1(t)$ for some $t\in r$}

$Y=$ {$z\in\mathbb{C}P^1:z=\gamma_2 \circ f(t)$ for some $t\in r$}


Then in $\mathbb{C}P^1/\sim$ we have:

$X \sim Y \iff \exists v\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall t\in r$ we have $$|\gamma_2\circ f(t)|^2=\frac{\left(|\gamma_1(t)|^2+1\right)\left(|\gamma_1(t)|-\Im(\gamma_1(t))\sin{v}\right)+|\gamma_1(t)|\left(|\gamma_1(t)|^2-1\right)\cos{v}}{\left(|\gamma_1(t)|^2+1\right)\left(|\gamma_1(t)|+\Im(\gamma_1(t))\sin{v}\right)-|\gamma_1(t)|\left(|\gamma_1(t)|^2-1\right)\cos{v}}$$ $\tag2$


My proof so far:
Let

$r\subset\mathbb{R}$ be connected

$\gamma_i(t):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}P^1$ for $i=1,2$

$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

$X=$ {$z\in\mathbb{C}P^1:z=\gamma_1(t)$ for some $t\in r$}

$Y=$ {$z\in\mathbb{C}P^1:z=\gamma_2 \circ f(t)$ for some $t\in r$}

$(p,q)=\left(\Re(\gamma_1(t)),\Im(\gamma_1(t))\right)$


Since $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$ we have $$\left(\lim_{w \rightarrow z}\frac{2\Re(w)}{|w|^2+1}, \lim_{w \rightarrow z}\frac{2\Im(w)}{|w|^2+1}, \lim_{w \rightarrow z}\frac{|w|^2-1}{|w|^2+1} \right)=\left(\frac{2\Re(z)}{|z|^2+1}, \frac{2\Im(z)}{|z|^2+1}, \frac{|z|^2-1}{|z|^2+1} \right),$$
then $\forall z=p+qi\in \mathbb{C}$ we can substitute $z=p+qi$ to compute $$C\circ R\left(S(z),(u,v))\right)$$
in terms of $p$ and $q$.
Thus, if $\infty\notin X$, by (1) we have:

$X \sim Y \iff \exists (u,v)\in\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $\forall t\in r$ we have $$\gamma_2\circ f(t)$$=$$\sqrt{\frac{(p^2+q^2+1)(\sqrt{p^2+q^2}-q\sin{v})+\sqrt{p^2+q^2}(p^2+q^2-1)\cos{v}}{(p^2+q^2+1)(\sqrt{p^2+q^2}+q\sin{v})-\sqrt{p^2+q^2}(p^2+q^2-1)\cos{v}}}\left(\frac{p\cos{u}-q\sin{u}+i(p\sin{u}+q\cos{u})}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}\right).$$

Since there always exists $u\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\gamma_2\circ f(t)=|\gamma_2\circ f(t)|\left(\frac{p\cos{u}-q\sin{u}+i(p\sin{u}+q\cos{u})}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}\right),$$
the following conditions are equivalent:

$\exists (u,v)\in\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $\forall t\in r$ we have $$\gamma_2\circ f(t)$$=$$\sqrt{\frac{(p^2+q^2+1)(\sqrt{p^2+q^2}-q\sin{v})+\sqrt{p^2+q^2}(p^2+q^2-1)\cos{v}}{(p^2+q^2+1)(\sqrt{p^2+q^2}+q\sin{v})-\sqrt{p^2+q^2}(p^2+q^2-1)\cos{v}}}\left(\frac{p\cos{u}-q\sin{u}+i(p\sin{u}+q\cos{u})}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}\right)$$
$\exists v\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall t\in r$ we have $$|\gamma_2\circ f(t)|$$=$$\sqrt{\frac{(p^2+q^2+1)(\sqrt{p^2+q^2}-q\sin{v})+\sqrt{p^2+q^2}(p^2+q^2-1)\cos{v}}{(p^2+q^2+1)(\sqrt{p^2+q^2}+q\sin{v})-\sqrt{p^2+q^2}(p^2+q^2-1)\cos{v}}}$$

Thus, if $\gamma_1$ is such that $\gamma_1(t)\in\mathbb{C}$ for all $t \in r$, we have:

$X \sim Y \iff \exists v\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall t\in r$ we have $$|\gamma_2\circ f(t)|^2=\frac{\left(|\gamma_1(t)|^2+1\right)\left(|\gamma_1(t)|-\Im(\gamma_1(t))\sin{v}\right)+|\gamma_1(t)|\left(|\gamma_1(t)|^2-1\right)\cos{v}}{\left(|\gamma_1(t)|^2+1\right)\left(|\gamma_1(t)|+\Im(\gamma_1(t))\sin{v}\right)-|\gamma_1(t)|\left(|\gamma_1(t)|^2-1\right)\cos{v}}$$


That's all I have so far. I don't know how to proceed with dealing with the case in which $X$ passes through $\infty$.
Any mixture of feedback on the proof so far and assistance with completing it are appreciated.
